# Como obter path do servidor sem ter iniciado FacesContext - execução de JOB?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, cdi

Tenho um JOB no qual eu preciso fazer o download de arquivos para poder usá-los.

Meu projeto é Java + JSF + CDI.

Ocorre que no momento da execução do JOB eu não tenho usuário logado e o retorno do FacesContext é nulo, pois não tenho sessão iniciada.

Li em vários lugares que eu poderia injetar ContextListener (por usar CDI), mas eu não estou conseguindo ter sucesso.

Como fazer para obter o endereço do servidor web?

Comment: que 'path' estamos falando aqui? tu diz a URL da tua aplicação? Não entendo o que teria a ver o ato de efetuar o download de arquivos com saber algo que necessite do FacesContext.

Comment: eu busco através de ftp um arquivo que está em outro servidor e preciso armazena-lo numa pasta do servidor para que eu possa abri-lo. Para mpvè-lo eu uso FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(urlLocal); e seguida: ftp.retrieveFile(nomeArquivo, fos) eu baixo e envio o arquivo para este path. Por isso eu preciso do caminho do servidor...

Comment: ta.. você precisa dizer qual a pasta quer salvar dentro do teu servidor da aplicação. Pra isso não seria uma URL no sentido `http://www.dominio/caminho/do/arquivo..` mas um Path relativo ao local do seu projeto ex `../pasta/relativa/ao/local/de/execucao/arquivo.txt`

Comment: O "FileOutputSream" ele transforma a url num caminho relativo como se fosse linha de comando do servidor e não funciona. Eu vou tentar eliminar a gravação local e tentar trabalhar com o arquivo em memória. Obrigado